# How to get folders and its files from the Directory

Tags: c#, file-io, directory-structure

I have retrieved file paths in text files. But I need now to retrieve the folders/directories/subdirectories and files from the path.  How can I achieve this with C#?

Answer (score 5):

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
var subdirs = dir.GetDirectories();
var files = dir.GetFiles();
```